# Fantasy book series involving three(?) brothers, one of whom turns out to be the reincarnation of a famous magic-wielding man

Tags: story-identification, books, magic, reincarnation

I can't remember the author's name or any of the titles of the books. Here's some things I do remember.

- The author is a woman and she's still writing more novels in this series, as recently as a few years ago. I started reading them around 2019 and I think there were at least three books in the series at the time.
- There are three(?) brothers, one is thought to be dead for a while.
- Another one turns out to be the reincarnation of a famous magic-wielding man. That dead man's wife ends up with this brother, because they're essentially the same person. This brother goes off to learn how to use the magic, and people recognize him as this other man reincarnated.
- There are a few gods(?) or otherwise supernatural beings, and one of them is the main antagonist. Another one (his name might be Pelis?) is mostly indifferent and then turns good after being stuck in a tower with the significant other of the reincarnated brother. The only way they escape is by having sex with each other (very fuzzy on the details here). This caused a lot of contention after it was discovered, but I think she and the brother ended up getting through it.
- There's another character, a young man or boy that befriends Pelis and later is taken to a kind of inter-dimensional place. His name might start with a 'T.'

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this and do you know roughly how many books there were in the series at the time?

Comment: I started reading them around 2019 maybe? And there were at least 3 I think. Pretty long books, I listened to the audiobooks.

Comment: You mentioned that Pelis had sex with the one brother's 'SO' (I assumed you meant 'significant other,' so I edited it to clarify that). To avoid any confusion, were you referring to the brother who was a reincarnation of a famous magic user?

Comment: The bit with the gods and the tower has the feel of *Hundred Thousand Kingdoms* but I'm not really placing any of the other details

Comment: @LogicDictates Thank you, yes, that's what I meant. The significant other of the brother who is the reincarnation, she and Pelis had sex in the tower and somehow that led to their escape. This caused a lot of contention after it was discovered, but I think she and the brother ended up getting through it.

Comment: *Deverry* series keeps coming up in searches.  I'm not personally familiar with it though.

Comment: @Radhil I looked up both of those and it's not either of them. Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: Is it a true reincarnation (that is, the main character is at least 16 (or so) years younger than the wife)? Or did the man gain the abilities/memories/other abilities when the famous magic-user died?

Comment: @mkennedy Yes, from what I remember it is a true reincarnation, but he doesn't initially remember anything from his previous life. Some of that does come later, if I recall.

Comment: Which service did you get the audiobooks from? It might narrow it down. Could almost be one of L.E.Modesitt's *Recluce* series?

Comment: I honestly don't remember which service it was. Probably Audible. Then again, I also seem to remember that this author was self-published, so maybe not. And not the Recluse series unfortunately 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found it. The author is Melissa McPhail, and the series is ***[A Pattern of Shadow and Light](https://www.goodreads.com/series/53227-a-pattern-of-shadow-light)*** (2010-2019). The first book is *[Cephrael's Hand](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/23911680-cephrael-s-hand)* (2010).

> In Alorin...three hundred years after the genocidal Adept Wars, the realm is dying, and the blessed Adept race dies with it. One man holds the secret to reverting this decline: Bjorn van Gelderan, a dangerous and enigmatic man whose shocking betrayal three centuries past earned him a traitor’s brand. It is the Adept Vestal Raine D’Lacourte’s mission to learn what Bjorn knows in the hope of salvaging his race. But first he’ll have to find him...
>
> In the kingdom of Dannym...the young Prince Ean val Lorian faces a tenuous future as the last living heir to the coveted Eagle Throne. When his blood-brother is slain during a failed assassination, Ean embarks on a desperate hunt for the man responsible. Yet his advisors have their own agendas, and his quest for vengeance leads him ever deeper into a sinuous plot masterminded by a mysterious and powerful man, the one they call First Lord...
>
> In the Nadori desert...tormented by the missing pieces of his life, a soldier named Trell heads off to uncover the truth of his shadowed past. But when disaster places him in the debt of Wildlings sworn to the First Lord, Trell begins to suspect a deadlier, darker secret motivating them.

[image: cover]

In case you were wondering, the character's names I sort of remember are Pelas (not Pelis) and Tanis. I'm pleased that the bits I remembered were mostly accurate!

Comment: Glad you found it. We'd be grateful if you'd mark your answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer), which you can do by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons. It's this site's way of formally indicating that a query has been solved to the querent's satisfaction.